# Rearranging columns in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a DataFrame with a lot of columns. Now I want to adjust the order of the columns.
A number of columns must come first (in a certain order) and the rest of the columns after them sorted by column name (not manually because there are many)

How can I achieve this using PySpark?

I guess sort them first and than adjust some in specific order

```
df.orderBy(cols, ascending=True)
```

Assume current column order:

```
col_a, col_k, col_c, col_h, col_e, col_f, col_g, col_d, col_j, col_i, col_b
```

Desired new order:

```
col_c, col_j, col_a, col_g :: col_b, col_d, col_e, col_f, col_h, col_i, col_k
```

Before `::` is columns in specific order, after is remaining columns ordered by column name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the first specific cols, sort the rest using python `sorted` then select in your df :

```
first_cols = ["col_c", "col_j", "col_a", "col_g"]
other_cols = sorted([c for c in df.columns if c not in first_cols], key=str.lower())

rearanged_cols = first_cols + other_cols
```

Then:

```
df = df.toDF(*rearanged_cols)
```

Or:

```
df = df.select(*rearanged_cols)
```